# Changing the selectedBackgroundColor in the auto-generated "more..." tab menu

Tags: ios7, titanium

I am developing an app using Titanium 3.2 for ios7. Is there a way to change the selectedBackgroundColor of a row in the auto-generated "more..." tab menu? I have no idea where or how to configure this menu so I do not have any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple ([TabBarController docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html)) you cannot style the "More view controller" which means you cannot configure its appearance in Titanium.

Answered by: Tim Poulsen on the Appcelerator Q&A. Posted here to assist others with similar questions.